# How do I make my character jump in any angle?

Tags: unity, c#, jumping

My character is a square which can spin in any angle but it can not jump in certain angle.

Can anyone help?

```
public class Player: MonoBehaviour {

  public float maxspeed = 10f;
  bool facingRight = true;

  Animator anim;

  bool grounded = false;
  public Transform groundCheck;
  float groundRadius = 0.2f;
  public LayerMask whatIsGround;
  public float jumpFocre = 500f;

  bool doubleJump = false;

  void Start ()
  {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
  }

  void FixedUpdate () {
    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

    if (grounded)
      doubleJump = false;

    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * maxspeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
  }

  void Update()
  {
    if((grounded || !doubleJump) && Input.GetKeyDown ("up"))
    {
      anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
      GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpFocre));

      if(!doubleJump && !grounded)
        doubleJump = true;
    }
  }

  void Flip()
  {
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently contains :

```
public float jumpFocre = 500f;
//...
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpFocre));
```

`Rigidbody2D.AddForce()` takes a `Vector2` as a parameter, so this can be changed to:

```
public Vector2 jumpDirection = new Vector2(0f, 1f);
public float jumpFocre = 500f;
//...
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpDirection.normalized * jumpFocre);
```

This will allow you to control both the magnitude and direction of the force applied for your jump by changing the values of `jumpFocre` and `jumpDirection`.

Comment: I still can't jump.

Comment: jump direction should be modified otherwise your character will continue jump only on the y component.

Comment: How do I modified it?

Comment: (1,0) is right, (0,1) is up, (1,1) is halfway in between.

Comment: How do I add them together?

Comment: `Vector2` supports the `+` operator, so `a = b + c` will work if they are all of type `Vector2`.

Comment: I'm new to coding, can you explain easier for me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public Vector2 jumpDirection = new Vector2(0f, 1f);
public float jumpFocre = 500f;
//...
float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
jumpDirection.x = move;
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpDirection.normalized * jumpFocre);
```

In this way you are giving to the jump force the x component that the user are triggering in that moment.

Comment: Do I put this in void update or void fixedupdate?

Comment: The variable declaration outside the function. The rest of the snippet in the if statement that you have in your update function.

Comment: I still can't jump.

Comment: did you step into code, your code enter in the if statement in the update function?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint, it's triggered?

Comment: How to I put in a breakpoint?

Comment: Besides the knowing how to add a breackpoint, try to make this change:
change this  if((grounded || !doubleJump) -> in this -> if((!doubleJump) && Input.GetKeyDown ("up")) and see what happen